# parse json values from array within object

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft within .net to parse json content and wish I had actually studied this better. I create an obj to parse the string text by listing all the children into a list of JTOkens and then grab the individual values from each JProperty. But now I need to capture a list of values and not sure how to that.

```
 Dim jobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(msg.Body.ToString())
 Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jobj.Children().ToList
 For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            If item.Name = "id" Then
                statid = item.Value
            End If
 etc...
```

But now I find the following item within the object and need all the "values" and "Tags"

```
{"results":
 {
 {
   "language": {
   "value": "ja"
},
"matching_results": [
{
  "value": "iPhone5",
  "tag": "JOE"
},
{
  "value": "iPhone5",
  "tag": "BOB"
}
],}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem while handling JSON and I find this solution:-

```
function jsonParse(data)
{
  if(typeof data=='object')
  {
    for(var obj in data)
    {
      if(obj=='value')
      {
        console.log('value---',data[obj])
      }
      else if(obj=='tag')
      {
        console.log('tag---',data[obj])
      }
      jsonParse(data[obj])
    }
  }      
}
```

Please remove all console with your variable, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a matter of breaking the object into token and reading the values into a list.

```
 Dim tags As List(Of JToken) = 
 item.Last.SelectToken("matching_results").Children()("tag").ToList
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to make this a useful answer - thanks.